# Understanding super in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Please consider the following code:

```
  `@interface Parent : NSObject

    - (void)whoAmI;

   @end

   @implementation Parent

   - (void)whoAmI
   {
     NSLog(@"PARENT CALLED");
   }

   @end

   @interface Child : Parent

   - (void)test;

   @end

   @implementation Child

   - (void)whoAmI
   {
      NSLog(@"CHILD CALLED");
   }

   - (void)test
  {
      NSLog(@"%@", [super class]);// CHILD!!!! why???
     [super performSelector:@selector(whoAmI)];// "CHILD CALLED" why???
  }

  @end
```

`

When i call `test` method i expect to see parent class printed and parent `whoAmI` method executed. But surprisingly both times the derived class is called. Can anyone explain why it happens and how do i `performSelector:` on base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `super` method is simply a way of forwarding a message to a superclass' implementation code. However, `self` remains the same. In fact, if you create an instance of `Child`, there is no instance of `Parent` at all. You can test this by NSLog-ing `self` as a `%p` to inspect the pointer address; when a super method is called, the `self` pointer is the same as it was for the instance of the subclass which called it:

Parent:

```
- (void)printAddr {
    NSLog(@"%p", self);
}
```

Child:

```
- (void)printAddr {
    NSLog(@"sub: %p, self");
    [super printAddr];
}
```

You will see that the pointers are the same if you call `[aChild printAddr];`.

Now let's translate this into addressing your specific questions. First off, look at the performSelector: method. Its default implementation is in NSObject, and this implementation most likely uses `self` to call the selector. Because of this, even though the method implementation is that of NSObject, the method will still be called on the *real* object, your subclass. If it weren't for this behavior, performSelector: would always try to call the method as if it were implemented directly on NSObject unless you implemented your own performSelector: on a subclass; obviously, this is the wrong behavior.

In addition, the same thing holds true for the `-class` method. Its default implementation resides on NSObject, and obviously it would be boring id it always returned `[NSObject class]`, so instead it effectively uses `self` to get the class of the *real* object.

You can also test what I've said here by making a method on the superclass which calls another method on `self`. Even if you use `super` to call the first method, the second method will still be called on your subclass since `self` still points to the subclass:

Parent:

```
- (void)method {
    NSLog(@"Parent: method");
    [self method1];
}
- (void)method1 {
    NSLog(@"Parent method1");
}
```

Child:

```
- (void)method {
    [super method];
}
- (void)method1 {
    NSLog(@"Child: method1");
}
```

In this case, `[aChild method]` will output:

```
Parent: method
Child: method1
```